# Add from two dictionaries with matching key into a List<myclass>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and they have one common key but the values are different for both of them.
I have a class (shown below) which accepts the key and values from both dictionaries and add.
Though I am close to resolving this problem but unable to get the start time right for each file. I want to add the filename, start time and End time into my List.
Here is my code:

```
public class PairedValues
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public PairedValues(string val1, DateTime val2, DateTime val3)
    {
        FileName = val1;
        StartTime = val2;
        EndTime = val3;
    }
}
```

//Main function code-

```
    public void GetData()
    {      
List<PairedValues> pairedValues = new List<PairedValues>(); 
    foreach (var f in dict1)
            {
                string dumpValue;
                var fileName = f.Key;
                var startTime = DateTime.Parse(f.Value);

                if (dict2.TryGetValue(fKey, out dumpValue))
                {
                    foreach (var p in dict2)
                    {
                        endTime = DateTime.Parse(p.Value);
                        var fileName = dumpValue;
                        pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues(f.Key, startTime , endTime));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

//Dictionaries

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>; //(<filename, starttime>)
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>; //(<filename, endTime>)
```

Comment: Do you want to merge the values for matching keys and discard non-matching values?

Comment: Why would you need to loop this?

 foreach (var p in dict2)
                
You already know this key exists in dict2, so just grab the endTime stored in dumpValue and  add to your paivedValues list: pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues(f.Key, startTime , endTime)); 

I also dont believe this is doing anything helpful var fileName = dumpValue;

Comment: Thanks for the input. Assuming the key (filename) is same in both the dictionaries, how can I get the start time from dict1? And the file name should be matched when checking start time and end time. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Silvermind - Most probably there will be no non-matching keys, only thing is that I want the start time from dict1 and end time from dict2 for each filename. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: @Nilanjan If the key doest exist, (dict2.TryGetValue(fKey, out dumpValue)) returns the value in the dumpValue variable. so then inside the if statement, you'd just need to do something like var endTime = DateTime.Parse(dumpValue);

Check out https://dotnetfiddle.net/VC2Pmr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in entering the nested foreach loop after you perform the call to `dict2.TryGetValue(fKey, out dumpValue)`. If that call returns true, you know the key exists and there's no point in searching for it.

But in fact, there's a simpler way and you don't even need `dumpValue`. Check if `dict2` contains the key, and if it does, grab the value using an indexer. I think maybe you don't know about the indexer and you might think that the only way to get at a value is by iterating over the Dictionary. Not so.

```
public void GetData()
{      
    List<PairedValues> pairedValues = new List<PairedValues>(); 

    foreach (var f in dict1)
    {
        var fileName = f.Key;
        var startTime = DateTime.Parse(f.Value);

        if (dict2.ContainsKey(f.Key))
        {
            endTime = DateTime.Parse(dict2[f.Key]);
            pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues(f.Key, startTime, endTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nilanjan, glad I could help. I'd appreciate it if you'd mark the question answered and/or upvote my answer.